# mysqli stat - are too many open tables bad?

Tags: mysql

I [debugged my $conn](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.stat.php) object and it gave me this output:

> Uptime: 6655360  Threads: 1  Questions: 471025  Slow queries: 0 
>   Opens: 3282  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 384  Queries per second
>   avg: 0.070

There are 384 open tables? Is that bad, and is it because I never close the connection?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/111634/open-tables-in-mysql

Comment: we have no contextual information which we could use to judge whether this is a reasonable figure or not. And we don't really know exactly how connections are being handled in your code, either. We don't know anything at all about your application in fact.

Comment: in short,as few as 384 table openings per 471025 queries is freaking good. nothing to worry about.

Comment: The 384 is how many tables are open currently. The count of table openings is 3282.

Comment: oops my bad. Still should be ok

Answer (score 3):

Also take a look at:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Threads%';
```

It will tell you how many current application connections there (Threads_connected) and how many of those are running a query at the current moment (Threads_running).

You can also see these threads with:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

The SQL query each thread is currently running will be shown. If there is no current query on a given thread, it will show "Sleep" as the command.

Each thread gets its own handle to table(s) it is querying. So the open tables is the sum total of all tables open by all threads.

You can see another view with:

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES FROM <database>;
+----------+-------------------+--------+-------------+
| Database | Table             | In_use | Name_locked |
+----------+-------------------+--------+-------------+
| test     | mytable           |      2 |           0 |
| test     | myothertable      |      0 |           0 |
+----------+-------------------+--------+-------------+
```

This example indicates `mytable` is currently being queried by two threads.

But this probably doesn't add up to your total open tables. It's normal for most threads to be "Sleeping" (i.e. not running a query, just connected).

MySQL maintains a "table cache" of open tables, so they're ready to be queried. There's no need to close a table handle if the table cache can hold them, and it makes the next query a little bit quicker. MySQL has one open tables cache, and all threads share it. The default size for the open tables cache in MySQL 8.0.4+ is 4000. In earlier versions of MySQL, the default size was different.

It isn't a problem to have open tables in the cache. That's intentional. If you have many threads connected, you might have read or written tables in many threads. Each thread gets its own handle to each table it has referenced. Maybe more than once per table per thread, if it was doing complex self-joins or subqueries.

See:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-cache.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_open_cache

Answer (score -2):

Actual question is do you need that much opened tables? And it answers your question

Comment: No I have 20 tables in sum.